# EEPROM dublicate pages

Tags: eeprom

I'm facing a strange issue. Whenever I write to my EEPROM (24LC04B), it gets written to every other page as well and I can't understand why.

**i2cdetect -y 1** returns 8 pages:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
 00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

first line of the first address: **i2cdump -y 1 0x50**:

```
15 15 20 10 10 00 00 00 00 18 18 18 18 18 18 00    ?? ??....??????.
```

first line of the third address (same data): **i2cdump -y 1 0x52**:

```
15 15 20 10 10 00 00 00 00 18 18 18 18 18 18 00    ?? ??....??????.
```

I update the 0x52 first block to 0x03: **i2cset -y 1 0x52 0x00 0x03**, the output of **i2cdump -y 1 0x52** is as expected and first block got updated to 0x03:

```
03 15 20 10 10 00 00 00 00 18 18 18 18 18 18 00    ?? ??....??????.
```

**BUT the first block of 0x50 address got updated as well**: **i2cdump -y 1 0x50**:

```
03 15 20 10 10 00 00 00 00 18 18 18 18 18 18 00    ?? ??....??????.
```

I can't understand why. It seems like every other address is a clone of each other:

```
0x50 = 0x52 = 0x54 = 0x56 (same data, if one gets updated, all get) 
0x51 = 0x53 = 0x55 = 0x57 (same data, if one gets updated, all get)
```

Any hints please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the 24LC04 is a 4096 **BIT** EEPROM, not 4096 byte. So you only have two pages of 256 byte.

If you read section 3.6 of the [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21708c.pdf), you see it doesn't care about bit 1 and bit 2 of the I²C device address either. The A0, A1, A2 inputs are not used at all in this chip.

So, that's why your chip is "mirrored" to 0x52, 0x54 and 0x56. And of course, the second page to 0x53, 0x55 and 0x57.